# How do I clone an empty bare repository with Ansible git module?

Tags: git, ansible

I have an empty and bare repository which I'm trying to clone with Ansible, but the git module is trying to checkout `master` and thus fails, since there is no such refspec in an empty repo.

My only way to get this working has been a shell command to just clone the repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried in every way and the only way that worked was to add `ignore_errors: true` and than check what made the Ansible module to fail.
I know it is not optimal but it works and we are not letting all the errors to pass thru:

```
- git: repo=<YOUR REPO> dest=<DEST>
  ignore_errors: true
  register: output
- name: check the error that failed the git module
  fail: msg="{{ output.msg }}"
  when: "'Failed to checkout branch master' not in output.msg"
```

BTW I filter the `output.msg` and not the `output.stderr` because for some reason on that specific error it goes out to the `.msg` but not to the `.stderr`.

Comment: Amazing! I was looking for this for a long time, Thanks!

Comment: I'm not working on this project anymore, but I'll accept this. At is looks to be correct